# Replicate Goldman Sachs' US Financial Condition Index

Tags: r, finance

I am trying to replicate Goldman Sachs' Financial Condition Index for the US.

Has anyone done something similar and could help me?

Thank you!

This is the data description:
(i) Policy Rate (4,4% weight): target Federal Funds Rate
(ii)    Riskless Bond Yield (45,1%): 10-year Treasury yield
(iii)   Corporate spread (39,6%): We use investment-grade domestic corporate spreads. For the US, this is the iBoxx domestic non-financials BBB 15Y+/10-year Treasury yield spread.
(iv)    Equity prices (4,9%): To get a stationary series for equity prices we use the ratio of a broad-based equity index to a lagged 10-year average of earnings per share, which has become known as the “Shiller P/E” ratio. The equity series is the S&P 500 for the US.
(v) Trade-weighted exchange rate (6,0%): We use the broad GS trade-weighted exchange rate index. This is the trade-weighted average of 36 bilateral exchange rates, with weights that reflect each economy’s exports, imports and third-market competition of domestic firms vis-à-vis foreign firms.

Comment: Do you have access to all series? If so, what have you tried so far? Seems it is simply normalized to October 20, 2003 = 100.

Comment: @AKdemy Yes, I have access. I just couldn't find where to attach here. I have tried a linear model using all the components, but the result is very different from the weights in the paper.

Comment: What exactly do you try to replicate? Not the index, but the computation of the weights? You did not mention this in the question.

Comment: The weights come from the FRB/US model and Goldman's own modelling according to this [paper](http://www.princeton.edu/~mwatson/papers/USMPF-2010.pdf). Goldman's models are explained [here](https://www.gspublishing.com/content/research/en/reports/2017/04/20/c10f888f-4faa-4ffc-b4c2-518cf5ffffe3.html)